# Python: TypeError: unbound method, must be called with (class) instance

Tags: python

Could someone help me understand this bug? Inside my class "Creature" I have this:

```
def mate_action(self):
    if self.mate == 1:
        for creature in creature_list:
            if creature.mate == 1:
                self.str_nb = (self.str + creature.str) / 2
                self.attr_nb = (self.attr + creature.attr) / 2
                self.cons_nb = (self.cons + creature.cons) / 2
                self.size_nb = (self.size + creature.size) / 2
                creature.mate = 0
                creature_list.append(Creature)
                for creature in creature_list:
                    if creature.alive == 0:
                        creature.alive = 1
                        creature.str = self.str_nb
                        creature.attr = self.attr_nb
                        creature.cons = self.cons_nb
                        creature.size = self.size_nb
                        creature.nb = 1
```

When I do this:

```
for creature in creature_list:  
    creature.mate_action()
```

And I receive this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method mate_action() must be called with Creature instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Are you sure your class is named `Creature` and not `creature`?  Note the leading capital letter.

Comment: What is the contents of creature_list?

Comment: @jedwards it is inside, indented correctly

Comment: @BenHare creature_list = [Creature(i) for i in range(50)]

Comment: @GabeWeiner I edited my comment -- can you verify it's capitalized?  If it is, do you have something like `creature = Creature` somewhere (instead of `creature = Creature()`.

Comment: You have `creature_list.append(Creature)` in your code.  I think you meant `creature_list.append(Creature())`.

Comment: you are correct! that solved the issue... created another one, but I can work on that one :) thank you

Comment: I'm happy your problem was solved.  Since Stack Overflow is mostly dedicated to future readers, questions such as this that were caused by a simple typographical error tend to be closed and eventually deleted.  If you would be so kind as to speed up that process by clicking the `delete` link that shows up near the bottom of the question, that would be greatly appreciated.  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by @zondo. I needed to change `creature_list.append(Creature)` to `creature_list.append(Creature())`